# Symfony search, parametr is not sending

Tags: php, symfony, search, model-view-controller

my entities: Advert is OneToMany relation to Address, and Address is OneToMany with City. In City I got around 200~ cities which user can pick 1 from EntityType. I'm trying to do search-engine(?) that user can filter adverts by city. I'm not sure I know how to do it well, my searchController has 1 action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search/city", name="search_city")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function searchCityAction(Request $request)
{
    $search = new City();

    $form = $this->createForm(CityType::class, $search)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ["label" => "Szukaj"]);


    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    if($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST))
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $selectedCity = ($_REQUEST['city']['city']);

        $address = $entityManager->getRepository(Address::class)->findBy(["city" => $selectedCity]);
        $searched = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["address" => $address]);

        return $this->render("Search/searched.html.twig", ["searched" => $searched]);
    }


    return $this->render("Search/index.html.twig", ["form" => $form->createView()]);
}
```

index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

searched.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% for search in searched %}
        {{ search.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In controller in $selectedCity I got good city's id. But later somehow parametr is missing. In Advert entity I got variable $address, in address I got variable $city and I tried to take this from DB in these 2 lines:

```
$address = $entityManager->getRepository(Address::class)->findBy(["city" => $selectedCity]);
$searched = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["address" => $address]);
```

but anyway it's not working, and I think I combinated much and I got lost here

## Edit

I tried to do this first solution, but it's not working. I changed my code like:

```
if($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST))
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $selectedCity = ($_REQUEST['city']['city']);

        $address = $entityManager->getRepository(Address::class)->findBy(["city" => $selectedCity]);
        $addressIds = $address->map(function($single_address) {
            return $single_address->id;
        });
        $searched = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["address" => $addressIds]);

        return $this->render("Search/searched.html.twig", ["searched" => $searched]);
    }
```

> method "map" not found in array...

Error on site:

> Call to a member function map() on array

Here's the definition variables code from my entities:

Advert class:

```
/**
 * @var Address
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $address;
```

Address class:

```
/**
 * @var Advert[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Advert", mappedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $adverts;

/**
 * @var City
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="addresses")
 */
private $city;
```

City class:

```
/**
 * @var Address[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="city")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $addresses;
```

Comment: I think you would be better off making a repository so you have a method for searching each. Then use the [`Criteria` pattern](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) ([this shows another interesting use case](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering)) with parameters for the search pieces and call it from your controller method: `$results = $this->addrRepo->searchByCity($cityName);`

Comment: Or (e.g.) you could combine Criteria's (as in the Knp example) to expand your search options: `$this->addrRepo->searchByCriteria($criteria)`, with `$criteria` being an array of `Criteria` objects to apply.

Comment: can you explain me step by step how to do it on my example? I really got lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query entities from database using Doctrine Entity Manager `findBy` method, the data will be returned as a `ArrayCollection` of Entity objects. Therefore, you can not passed them directly as a parameter of another `findBy` function.

In the example you post `$address` is a collection of `Address` instances. You can extract an array of ID from the collection and query the `Advert` with them. For example:

```
$searched = $entityManager->getRepository(Advert::class)->findBy(["address" => $addressIds]);
```

Assume that `Address` class has a default key property called `id`, you can extract the list of address ids using `ArrayCollection.map` function:

```
$addressIds = $addresses->map(function($single_address) {
   return $single_address->id;
})
```

This one way to achieve what you are trying to do. But not the only and actually the better way.

Basically, if you do a `bi-directional` (2 ways) relationship between `Address` and `Advert` entity. You can simply access the list of `Advert` entity that linked to a `Address` entity using:

`$address->adverts`

Which I assume that you `adverts` is the property of the `Address` class mapped to `Advert` class.

More one querying and establishing relationship with Doctrine and Symfony can be found here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: Yep finally it's working. I had to change a little bit your code like:
        $addressIds = array_map(function($single_address) {
        return $single_address->id;
    }, $address);

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps, the code I posted is just an example based on the assumption that your symfony version ArrayCollection supported helper function like map. If you find it's helpful, can you please upvote or mark the answer as accepted.